# RSS Feed Validator Issue

Tags: rss

I have a site that has a "brad-thor-blog" custom post type. The feed for this should be http://www.bradthor.com/brad-thor-blog/feed/ ... Attempting to use this, I get an error: "error on line 197 at column 31: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0x0C 0xE2 0x80 0x9C"

I've run this through the w3c validator as well, which says there is a space character in one particular post (http://www.bradthor.com/brad-thor-blog/the-first-commandment/) that is causing this error, but I don't see this anywhere in the post (or in the code).

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not sure if my answer will help anyone or not, but I was able to track this down by using the w3 feed validator service (http://validator.w3.org/), which showed me what line the error was on. Then I copied the post into Sublime Text, found the illegal character and removed it. Everything worked fine.